# I can't launch Chrome driver without specifying path

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I keep getting an error message as well as others in Selenium Python when I use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH or:
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities.
```

I keep getting this message as well as others in Selenium Python.  I can get around this with:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Bain3\Music\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(' http://stackoverflow.com' )
```

I have tried the following to remedy this issue with Chrome and Firefox:
Reinstalling Chrome, Firefox, Pycharm, Anaconda, Selenium (pip install selenium)

Changing directory of file: https://ibb.co/huDuWk

This issue occurred after reinstalling Chrome and Firefox.
Directories are:

```
C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3
C:\Brother\geckodriver.exe
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

I am using windows 10
Thanks

Comment: what is the os that you are using?

Comment: Have you tried putting the folder that has chromedriver in your PATH?

Comment: @santhoshkumar I am using windows

Comment: @BryanOakley I just tried Chromedriver and this works.  Geckodriver does not seem to work.  I did have different versions of firefox (nightly, developer and beta at one stage but deleted all of them).  Maybe it's trying to access one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to set the path

- Place the `chromedriver.exe`'s path into `PATH` (on Windows computer ), so your `PATH` setting is correct, but you need to call the default constructor to use it .

  `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
- Specify the path in `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='some path')`. Here you need the full path to the executable, not the directory where you store the path .

  `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\sankalp\\chromedriver.exe')`

Choose either one you want.

Comment: My path directory for gecko does not seem to register at all.  The second option works perfectly.  It'd be great if they had export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/of/executable/downloaded/ or something similar for windows users.  As it seems weird that I have to reset my pc and install linux to use geckodriver.  I am going to test this on my laptop to see if this issue is present for this pc only or if it's something I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to update the Path environment variable in windows. Just append the existing variable value with the folder path which actually consists your chrome/gecko drivers. This document may help you,

https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf

**Note** - Although we can get rid of adding the executable_path by doing this,this is not preferable. Because in future it may create conflicts with the driver version that you are going to use. Instead of updating the path variable permanently, I suggest you to store the value of the executable_path in a variable and pass it in your scripts. In this way you can have a better control over the driver versions.

For storing the driver path in variable, below line may give you some idea.

```
geckoPath=r'C:\Users\Bain3\Music\geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckoPath)
driver.get(' http://stackoverflow.com' )
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: This tutorial is for Chromedriver and Java?  Can you explain how I would do that in Python?  It doesn't seem to recognise geckodriver.exe.  I have also tried changing the path of geckodriver

Comment: Yes correct. The concept is same. Just put the geckodriver in a folder and append that path to environment variable. Then in command prompt try hitting geckodriver not geckodriver.exe. I haven't tested this but i believe this will work. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you try adding chromdriver as per in the doc and check if it works?

Comment: Yeah Chromedriver works. 
 Gecko gives .selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH and is not recognised by commandline unless I run it's full directory install

Comment: Is the name of the geckodrive executable is geckodrive.exe? If it is Gecko.exe we need to give Gecko in command prompt

Comment: Can you explain how to executable_path in a variable and pass it in your scripts.  From what I see the directory should be the same in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to set the path MyCopmuter - > properties -> Environment Variables -> there set your path.
Then the example code below:

```
    from selenium import webdriver        
    webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\Users\xyz\\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(' http://stackoverflow.com' )
    filename="stack_screen_shot"
    #to save in a file in output folder
    browser.save_screenshot("C:\\Users\\xyz\\PycharmProjects\\output\\"+file_name+".png")
```